# Pushing my configuration files to VMs. What’s a good tool to bring this under source control?

Tags: configuration, configuration-management, source

I have a couple of VMs where I go and edit Nginx config files, fail2ban config files, php-fpm files etc.

I want to move this to source control and push it out. Sort of similar to this

https://zachholman.com/2010/08/dotfiles-are-meant-to-be-forked/

what’s a good way to do this? Are there scripts/tools to help me here? Bonus if they can restart/reload services on file change/etc.

Comment: If you read the information on the tag [tag:configuration-management] you'll find the tags of a few different tools. Then read up on those and choose which one fits your needs buest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Ansible for pushing out to many servers. It's agentless, you only need sshd and python. Any system besides RHEL5 basically works out of the box.

Make your top Ansible directory (`/etc/ansible`) a Git repository.

Do a 'code review' procedure with your colleague before pushing wide.

Yes, it gets the bonus for being able to reload services. Install `apt` or `yum` packages. Tons of other stuff.

As it's the basic use-case of Ansible, any tutorial will cover it.